# Snowflake Parent Child Hierarchy Weighting

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with three columns illustrating a weighted parent child hierarchy relationship e.g.

Table

| parent | child | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | 0.4 |
| a | c | 0.6 |
| b | d | 0.2 |
| b | e | 0.2 |
| b | f | 0.6 |

The hierarchy dictates that b and c are components of a, with weighting 0.4 and 0.6 respectively.

Child b also has subcomponents d, e, and f with weights 0.2, 0.2, and 0.6.

I'm able to illustrate the hierarchy using a connect by query mapping parent = prior child.

Resulting Table

| hierarchy | parent | child | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | a | b | 0.4 |
| a | a | c | 0.6 |
| a to b | b | d | 0.2 |
| a to b | b | e | 0.2 |
| a to b | b | f | 0.6 |

I need to supplement this table with an additional column showing the true weight of the lowest level child c,d,e,f to the highest parent a.

| parent | child | scaled_weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | c | 0.6 |
| a | d | 0.08 |
| a | e | 0.08 |
| a | f | 0.24 |

What's the best way to map the parent to the lowest level children with their "true" weights?

Answer (score 1):

So we start with how to find the "true parents" which is the rows where the parent is not in the child column, thus a LEFT JOIN that matches nothing:

```
with data(parent, child, weight) as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES 
        ('a','b',0.4),
        ('a','c',0.6),
        ('b','d',0.2),
        ('b','e',0.2),
        ('b','f',0.6)          
)
select a.* 
from data as a
left join data as b
    on a.parent = b.child
where b.child is null;
```

gives:

| PARENT | CHILD | WEIGHT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | 0.4 |
| a | c | 0.6 |

now, we can put this into a recursive CTE so solve for us.

```
select a.parent,
    a.child,
    a.weight,
    array_construct(a.parent, a.child) as path 
from data as a
left join data as b
    on a.parent = b.child
where b.child is null

union all

select r.parent
    ,d.child
    ,d.weight * r.weight as weight
    ,array_append(r.path, d.child) as path
from rec_cte as r
join data as d 
    on r.child = d.parent
```

which gives:

| PARENT | CHILD | WEIGHT | PATH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | 0.4 | [ "a", "b" ] |
| a | c | 0.6 | [ "a", "c" ] |
| a | d | 0.8 | [ "a", "b", "d" ] |
| a | e | 0.8 | [ "a", "b", "e" ] |
| a | f | 2.4 | [ "a", "b", "f" ] |

now it seems you also want the first row to not show as it's part of the `a,b,d`, `a,b,e`, and `a,b,f` rows

which presently, I am stumped on. so will stop here for now..

### Common parent removal:

```
with recursive rec_cte as ( 
    select a.parent,
        a.child,
        a.weight,
        array_construct(a.parent, a.child) as path,
        null::TEXT as del_p,
        null::TEXT as del_c
    from data as a
    left join data as b
        on a.parent = b.child
    where b.child is null
    
    union all
    
    select r.parent
        ,d.child
        ,d.weight * r.weight as weight
        ,array_append(r.path, d.child) as path
        ,r.parent as dep_p
        ,d.parent as del_c
    from rec_cte as r
    join data as d 
        on r.child = d.parent
), to_deletes as (
    select r.del_p, r.del_c, r.del_p is null, r.del_p = '', r.del_p is not null 
    from rec_cte as r
)
select 
    r.parent,
    r.child,
    r.weight,
    r.path
from rec_cte as r
left join to_deletes as d
    on r.parent = d.del_p and r.child = d.del_c
where d.del_p is null
```

gives:

| PARENT | CHILD | WEIGHT | PATH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | c | 0.6 | [ "a", "c" ] |
| a | d | 0.8 | [ "a", "b", "d" ] |
| a | e | 0.8 | [ "a", "b", "e" ] |
| a | f | 2.4 | [ "a", "b", "f" ] |